# How to setup a CSV web datasource

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, url, microsoft-excel-2011

In Excel, I can import a CSV from the web as text by simply pasting in the URL as a file name, but when I ask Excel to update, it has stripped the URL and tries to find a file on the local hard drive instead.

When I try to import using a web query, excel seems to assume that I want to scrape a html page.

Is there some feature I've missed that will allow me to set up a CSV web source?

Comment: can you download the CSV?  or do you have a specific reason/issue for the need to access the CSV from Excel via a web URL?

Comment: Yes, the data will change. I found out that I won't get any errors on updates if I uncheck the file request ... but haven't verified yet if it actually works :)